# Iterator Returning "Junk" on the Last Element

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic

I am working with some dynamically allocated arrays and I know this has to be some sort of range problem with the array but I can't figure out what it is. When the iterator gets to the final relevant data point, dereferencing the pointer that points to the element just prints junk every time. m_data is the array that holds the data and is of type T because it is a container template. Any suggestions would be much appreciated as always. Here are a few pertinent snippets:

```
---From sorted.cpp---

template <class T>
typename sorted<T>::const_iterator sorted<T>::insert(T data){

  if (m_size == m_capacity){    
    cout << "Resizing array." << endl;
    resize();
  }

  cout << "Adding " << data << " to array." << endl;
  m_size++;
  m_data[m_size - 1] = data;
  if (m_size > 10){ // This test output works fine.
    cout << "Array should be: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)     
      cout << m_data[i] << " ";
    cout << endl; 
  }

  return const_iterator(&m_data[m_size - 1]);   

}

template <class T>
void sorted<T>::resize(){

  int newCapacity = (2 * m_capacity);
  T *temp_array = new T[newCapacity];

  for (int i = 0; i < m_capacity; i++)
    temp_array[i] = m_data[i];

  T *m_data = temp_array;
  delete [] temp_array;
  setCap(newCapacity);

}

---From test file---

int main() {

  sorted<int> x;
  sorted<int>::const_iterator itr;

  // append some values into my_array x
  for (int i = 1; i < 12 ; i++ ) 
    x.insert( (i*i) % 19 );

  // my_array does not keep items in order
  cout << "my_array x:" << endl;
  for (itr = x.begin(); itr != x.end(); itr++)
    cout << *itr << " ";
  cout << endl << endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the iterator works as it should?

Comment: `T *m_data = temp_array;` - seriously, that doesn't belong **declared** in that member function. Pretty sure just `m_data = temp_array;` will do much better.

Comment: WhozCraig - I think you're right. Now that I realized my mistake with m_data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resize looks suspicious:

```
void sorted<T>::resize(){

  int newCapacity = (2 * m_capacity);
  T *temp_array = new T[newCapacity];
```

so temp_array is a new array with new size

```
  for (int i = 0; i < m_capacity; i++)
    temp_array[i] = m_data[i];
```

above you have copied old data to new array

```
  T *m_data = temp_array;
  delete [] temp_array;
```

and here (in above code) you delete temp_array which is your new array. So the fix is to replace above to:

```
  delete [] m_data;
  m_data = temp_array;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was thinking about the deallocation all wrong, obviously. Just a novice still struggling with pointers here. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @swing try using `unique_ptr<T[]>` -- much less resource tracking work.  And it generates errors immediately when raw `T*` code would instead lead to UB in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a variable m_data in resize() when you really wanted to use the classe's m_data.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that m_data wasn't a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, but rather an array itself. That was my problem. *facedesk*